# Android changing text color on popup menu

Tags: android, popupmenu, textcolor

In my app, when I click on the three dot button, menu items appear in white text color on white background. I wanted to change the text color to black but it doesn't work. I've looked for solutions but none of them worked. 
Here's my code:

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppMaterialTheme" parent="SuperMaterialTheme">

</style>


<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="SuperMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>

</style>


<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>

</style>



<style name="PopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>

</style>
```

Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme"
>
```

Where's the mistake? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The menu you're asking for is called the Overflow Menu.You can change the color of the overflow menu background by adding a new style in style.xml.

```
  <style name="OverflowMenu"
  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyOverflowMenu</item>
  <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyOverflowMenu" 
  parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
  <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/your_color</item> 
  </style>
  <style name="TextAppearance">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
  </style>
```